# C# HashSet union on IEnumerable within LINQ Func expression does not work (possible precompiler bug)

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, union, aggregate, hashset

I am using using Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0.

I have run into this using Aggregate on a `Dictionary<T, List<T>>` to extract the set of type `T` values used across all type `List<T>` lists in the dictionary. Here is the simplest case I could come up with that exhibits the same behaviour.

First, as the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) states, the following *does* work:

```
var set = new HashSet<int>();
var list = new LinkedList<int>();
var newSet = set.Union(list);
```

That is, I can call `Union` on a `HashSet` with a `List` as the argument (since it implements `IEnumerable`).

Whereas, the equivalent expression within a `Func` argument of the LINQ `Aggregate` expression produces an error (precompiler at least):

```
new List<int>[] { new List<int>() }.Aggregate(new HashSet<int>(), (acc, list) => acc.Union(list));
```

It expects the argument of Union to be HashSet, and will cooperate if it is given one, contrary to its behaviour outside LINQ/Func expressions.

The real world example I was using when I came across the problem was:

```
public AdjacencyListGraph(Dictionary<TVertex, LinkedList<TVertex>> adjacencyList)
{
    var vertices = adjacencyList.Aggregate(new HashSet<TVertex>(),
    (vertices, list) => vertices.Union(list.Value));
}
```

Which complains that it cannot convert `IEnumerable<TVertex>` to `HashSet<TVertex>`...

Comment: I'm curious, what do you mean by 'precompiler'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually lies in trying to replace the accumulator type of HashSet with the IEnumerable, .Union method doesn't add items to HashSet, but returns the new IEnumerable on the resulting union.

You should change your code to the following:

```
    // select from keys
    var vertices = new HashSet<TVertex>(adjacencyList.Keys);
```

or

```
    // select from values
    var vertices = new HashSet<TVertex>(adjacencyList.SelectMany(dictEntry => dictEntry.Value));
```

Comment: Your first example would not produce what my expression is trying to achieve. I am looking to take the union of all of the adjacencyList's Values, which are lists, not to get the eet of the indices for those lists.

Comment: That's why I added the second. Your intentions couldn't be deduced from the incorrect code.

Comment: Sorry I was just about to reply, the second does do what I want, thanks.

Comment: However I'm not sure why I can't do what I did originally. I intended to replace the accumulator... like in a ruby inject

Comment: Ah... The following does work: var vs = adjacencyList.Aggregate((IEnumerable<TVertex>) new HashSet<TVertex>(), (vertices, list) => vertices.Union(list.Value));

Comment: I think it is quite poor that I have to cast a HashSet to an IEnumerable to make this work. The code is unambiguous. Thanks for your help though, you correctly identified the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is in your understanding of the `Select` method.  The lambda passed in does not recieve the list but instead elements of the list.  So the variable you've named `list` is in fact of type `int` which is not compatible with `Union`.

Here is a more explicit example of what you're trying to do

```
new List<int>().Select( (int list) => new HashSet<int>().Union(list));
```

With the type infererence removed it's much clearer why this doesn't work.

Comment: You're quite right, I am using Select wrongly in the above example, it should have read something like this:

    new List<int>[] {new List<int>()}.Select(list => new HashSet<int>().Union(list));

In my real world case you van see that list is a genuine list.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> new List<int>().Select(list => new HashSet<int>().Union(list));
> ```

I think you would expect to use `SelectMany` here, unless you want the result to be `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`.